# How do I apply a shopping price rule discount to each individual sku's price?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

customers receive 10% off your entire order when you purchase 4 or more items…

but…

we need the discount to be applied to each individual sku's price, not the row total and/or order subtotal.

Currently when pulling order info, magento shows the full purchase price of an item and will apply the discount to the subtotal of the order.

Alternatively, applying a "catalog price rule" when you purchase 4 or more items would probably work.

Comment: You have already answered your question.

Comment: I get the general concept I think, but am looking for code specifics as far as actually applying the change. What variables and how to apply to what template etc...

Comment: I think @TimBezhashvyly is saying you answered the question here:
> applying a "catalog price rule" when you purchase 4 or more items would probably work

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is that.

[image: First]

[image: Second]