# Magento 1.9.1 Cart Pricing Rules: discount on X products or more

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to create a rule that does the following: when you buy 12 or more products a discount of 18% is given per item - not on the total amount of the cart.

I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Question: how can this be achieved?

---

[image: My Cart Rules]

Here is my cart rules page with the drop down open

Comment: are you looking for something like that?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19211/how-do-i-apply-a-shopping-price-rule-discount-to-each-individual-skus-price/60275#60275

Comment: It is not completely clear what you want Michael. Suppose we have 14 products in cart: do you then want to apply the discount only to those 12? If so, please try to describe it in a little more detail. Or with an example. You need a combination of conditions (TAB) and `Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
You need to go to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Rule

You just need to adjust the 4 to your number and then that should work smoothly

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Comment: The would be perfect if my install had the option of "By Percentage of the original price" It seems I may have a bigger issue since that option is not available in my drop down.

Comment: But you are in Catalog Price Rule ?

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Sorry for adding a new answer but I couldn't see how to add an image to a comment. Your screenshot shows an amount condition under Catalog Price Rule. That is not an option that shows for me under conditions... Thank you for your assistance
![Catalog Price Rules][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YDdHL.png

Comment: You chose category is 4 not amount

Comment: That is because Quantity doesn't show as an option http://i.stack.imgur.com/PcvKE.png

Comment: I updated it again, try and see if that works that is a shopping cart price rule now